# Spring delegating instanciation to another thread

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, javafx

I'm trying to make a javafx app working with springboot.

Everything works fine till now, but i want spring to instanciate some Stages and push them in the SpringContext.
However, only the JavaFX main thread is able to instanciate those objects, otherwise, a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread` will be thrown.

Is there any way to delegate the instanciation to another thread (basiclly trying to do a simple `Platform.runLater` call) and leaving spring aware of the instanciated object (it has to be in the spring context) ?